# Convert UTM coordinates to latitude and longitude with geopandas

Tags: python, geopandas

I want to convert this [file](https://github.com/jddorellanao/fisicarocas/tree/main/geopandas) UTM geometry to a latitude and longitude assigning a CRS.

```
import geopandas as gpd
df = gpd.read_file('dataframe.shp')
df = df.set_crs('epsg:6362')
```

I got no coordinates

[image]

By transforming the geometry to a new CRS I perform the conversion.

```
df_ = df.to_crs('epsg:4482')
```

[image]

How can I convert the UTM coordinates into a latitude and longitude without first setting a CRS and then converting it to another CRS?

Comment: Do you call `.set_crs('epsg:6362')` because your shapefile doesn't have a matching `.prj` file? If it does, you shouldn't need that call, and the call to `to_crs()` is unavoidable, since you'll need to tell `geopandas` what you want to convert to?

Comment: @Grismar then how do I convert the UTM to Lat,Long?

Comment: `to_crs("epsg:4326")`

Comment: Thank you @RobRaymond, you gave me the idea to define a default CRS and then convert the coordinates to the CRS of the user's choice. As always your comments are very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- there is no **prj** file so there is no defined CRS in this Shapefile
- either save again with a CRS or each time you will need to set the CRS before re-projecting it

```
import geopandas as gpd
import tempfile
from pathlib import Path
import requests
import io
url = "https://github.com/jddorellanao/fisicarocas/raw/main/geopandas/dataframe.shp"

with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as d:
    for ext in ["cpg","shp","shx","dbf"]:
        r = requests.get(url.replace("shp", ext))
        with open(Path(d).joinpath(r.url.split("/")[-1]), "wb") as f:
            f.write(r.content)
    df = gpd.read_file(Path(d).joinpath(url.split("/")[-1]))
    
df.crs
```